# Why PAGE CSS is not functioning?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to export HTML text as word document with A4 size and portrait orentation and my javascript allow me to export text as document but like a webpage format not A4 nor potrait and I added @page CSS to do that but it's not working So how should I modify my css or javascript to make it done and this is my [script](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G4OZ78ZCYNLV)

```js
function Export2Doc(element, filename = ''){
    var preHtml = "<html xmlns:o='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office' xmlns:w='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40'><head><meta charset='utf-8'><title>Export HTML To Doc</title></head><body>";
    var postHtml = "</body></html>";
    var html = preHtml+document.getElementById(element).innerHTML+postHtml;

    var blob = new Blob(['\ufeff', html], {
        type: 'application/msword'
    });
    
    // Specify link url
    var url = 'data:application/vnd.ms-word;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(html);
    
    // Specify file name
    filename = filename?filename+'.doc':'document.doc';
    
    // Create download link element
    var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");

    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
    
    if(navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob ){
        navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, filename);
    }else{
        // Create a link to the file
        downloadLink.href = url;
        
        // Setting the file name
        downloadLink.download = filename;
        
        //triggering the function
        downloadLink.click();
    }
    
    document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
}
```

```css
  @page
{
    size:21cm 29.7cmt;  /* A4 */
    margin:1cm 1cm 1cm 1cm; /* Margins: 2.5 cm on each side */
    mso-page-orientation: portrait;  
}
@page Section1 { }
div.Section1 { page:Section1; }
```

```html
<div id="exportContent">
<div class=Section1>

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. 

</div>
</div>

<button onclick="Export2Doc('exportContent');"> EXPORT  </button>
```

Comment: Where is there an extra `t` in `cm` (units) in the first line of the `@page`?

Answer (score 1):

```
page[size="A4"] {
  background: white;
  width: 21cm;
  height: 29.7cm;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 0.5cm;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.5cm rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
@media print {
  body, page[size="A4"] {
    margin: 0;
    box-shadow: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: I added your CSS it appears in web page as A4 ans portrait [script](https://codepen.io/ZACK_G/pen/eaXLjo) but when I export it does not appear with A4 size at all so how can modify css or javascript to export document as A4 and portrait and thanks for your help